# How to hide this specific text from a <TR> in a TABLE HTML CODE

Tags: css

I am trying to hide this:

```
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="col-image all" data-name="image" data-orderable="false" data-searchable="false" data-width="200px" data-priority="4">Image</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

And this is my attempt:

```
thead.col-image all {
  display: none;
}
```

^ this didn't work - any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly you want to hide `thead, tr or th`. also you are missing a dot(.) in here `thead.col-image all`  should be `thead.col-image .all `

Comment: Or rather `thead .col-image.all`.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the wrong element and ALSO 'all' is not a selector;

```
thead.col-image all {} // is calling e.g. <thead class="col-image">
```

It should be

```
thead tr th.col-image.all { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 2):

`thead.col-image all` means `<all>` tags in `<thead class='col-image'>`

correct css for your code should be

```
thead .col-image.all {
  display: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pb5k4v63/26/

Answer (score 0):

with `<th>` tag only heading will disappear.

Attach a class for `<th>`or `<td>` or `<tr>` depending on your requirement.
and for that class apply the property
{visibility:hidden} which will not affect alignment of your table.
where as {display:none} can affect the alignment (though it works.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use class for td th or add a span to text you want to hide and add class to it

```css
.hide{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>hello</td>
<td class="hide">hide me</td>
<td>and also <span class="hide">hide me</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** Wrap your `<thead>`, `<th>`, etc. within the `<table>` element. Also make sure you are calling the proper elements in your CSS.

An HTML table is defined with the `<table>` tag.

So in essence you have the `<th>`, `<thead>`, etc. elements operating outside of a `<table>`, so you are breaking your code because the `<th>`, `<thead>`, etc. require the parent `<table>` element to function properly.

Why you may ask? As stated above a table is defined with the `<table>` tag, so you do not really have a table on your page.

In conclusion "wrap your tables rows, heads, etc within the `<table>` element for now on.

Here is the code:

HTML

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="col-image all" data-name="image" data-orderable="false" data-searchable="false" data-width="200px" data-priority="4">Image</th>
</tr>
</thead> 
</table>
```

CSS

```
th.col-image.all{
  display: none;
}
```

You can view the code live here: https://jsfiddle.net/W3Develops/nbf17pus/6/
I also added another table in there so you can see how to properly make a table.

Here is a link to Mozilla Developer Network and W3Schools so you can learn more about making tables. Good luck:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Also you were calling classes for `thead` when you should have been calling classes for `th`.

Cheers.